# Why this Immediately Invoked Function returns number?

Tags: javascript

I want to understand why this code returns `number`:

```
(function f(f){
    return typeof f();
})(function(){return 1;});
```

First I assume it will return `undefined` since function `f` executes before the last function, but then I run the code with console logs and the result was `number`. Anyone would mind explaining why this was the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f` inside the first function’s body refers to the parameter called `f`. An equivalent version without the confusing shadowing would be:

```
(function f(g){
    return typeof g();
})(function(){return 1;});
```

And an equivalent version with the IIFE separated into a function definition and a call:

```
function f(g) {
    return typeof g();
}

f(function () {
    return 1;
});
```

(If it’s not clear why *this* returns `'number'`, you should review the concept of functions as values before jumping into intentionally more complicated IIFEs with shadowing that also make use of the concept.)